# Autofac InstancePerRequest scope - reuse the scope instance to other places

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, autofac

I am using `Autofac` as a dependency injection container in my project. I would like to make use of `InstancePerRequest` scope as I don't want those objects to outlive a request.

Below is the code I am using in the gateway class where I know each of my request will pass through it.

```
        using (var scope = _container.BeginLifetimeScope(MatchingScopeLifetimeTags.RequestLifetimeScopeTag))
        {
            var service = scope.Resolve<MyTestService>();
            ...
        }
```

Now in my code I locate several other classes where I need to resolve the `MyTestService` which at the moment is causing an exception with a message `No scope with a Tag matching 'AutofacWebRequest'`. The exception is because I am calling the resolve on a `container` instance, whereas I should call resolve on the same `scope` instance, as shown above.

Can someone please help me to know how do I access the same `scope` instance at those places in my code? I can't keep calling the `BeingLifetimeScope` in all the classes.

Comment: [Have you read the docs?](http://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq/per-request-scope.html)

Comment: Yes I have read through it but it doesn't tell me where and how to retain the 'scope' instance when we need to access it from multiple places.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I'm stuck on a phone and my house is being remodeled so I have no computer access. As such you'll get a shorter answer with no code but it should unstick you.

You say you've read the docs, so you should know:

- When you create a scope in those using blocks it's not the same as the current request scope.
- If your service is used inside an existing request then you should just be injecting what the service needs right into the constructor, not doing service location with a scope.
- If your service is not used inside an existing request then you're on your own to figure out how to mimic a request around your service. There's no fixed way to deal with that since it's app specific.
- If the whole point in needing a request scope is to get dependencies registered per request to resolve outside a request then you should switch to instance per lifetime scope.
- If you must - and it's an anti-pattern, but if you must - you can put a constructor parameter in your service that is an ILifetimeScope. That will get the current scope injected.

It's not really possible from your question to tell *why* you need the scope. I'm guessing there may be better ways to do what you're trying to do but being stuck on my phone I can't really expand on the million possibilities and ways to work around doing what you say you need to do. In future questions consider explaining more about the context - why your service needs to pass through a "gateway" and why you're in the situation and not just injecting constructor parameters and letting Autofac integration do the heavy lifting.

Regardless, this should get you unstuck. If not, you'll need to clarify your question with additional context and maybe someone else can hop in.